# Как привязать код к окну

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно чтобы этот код работал в определённом окне, например в Chrome, но при этом это окно должно быть свернуто. Как это можно реализовать?

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import sys

def click(): 
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)     
        pyautogui.click()
        if keyboard.is_pressed('='):
            print("Пока-пока")
            sys.exit()                     

keyboard.add_hotkey('-', click)
keyboard.wait('Ctrl + Q')
```

Answer (score 0):

Приложенный вами код, не будет работать ни при каком варианте на скрытых окнах, тк как библиотека keyboard только симулирует ввод клавиатуры, соответственно для работы необходимо что бы окно было открыто. (как вариант вы можете запустить программу в виртуалке: vmware или virtualbox.).

Если вам необходимо провести какую то манипуляцию с хромом. То обратите внимание на selenium. Эта библиотека позволяет делать подобные вещи, а в headless mode браузер не будет даже отображаться на экране.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/